# Glumpy installation fails on MacOS using pip

Tags: macos, clang++, glumpy

The installation of Glumpy fails with clang error on MacOS (10.14) (and so does triangle but throws the same error). The error is that clang does not find the stdio.h file which is clearly on the system. Can I some how feed the location of stdio.h to the setup.py script?

I have tried to compile it from source but then I got into the depdence hell of python which I would like to avoid. Pip would be the optimal way

This is where it fails:

clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DVOID=void -DREAL=double -DNO_TIMER=1 -DTRILIBRARY=1 -DANSI_DECLARATORS=1 -Ic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c c/triangle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/c/triangle.o
    c/triangle.c:350:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

I am not sure why clang does not find its own includes on its own system but one would think this should be the case. Is there a way to solves this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include` exist?  Why are you specifying it at all as `/usr/include` will already be in the compiler's list of include paths?

Comment: Hi, I do not specify anything I just type the command  sudo pip install glumpy into the terminal and this is the error thrown. This is why I find it a bit weird. I do not specify any path. However you are right the path does not exsist. it is MacOSX10.15.sdk instead of MacOSX10.14.sdk. However I am not sure why this is but concerning this is a Mac computer and clang anything can happen here.

Comment: I would say that's an inherent bug in pip or whatever as there is no need to specify any of that stuff unless you are cross-compiling for iOS etc.  You should probably report it upstream.

Comment: Could it happen that this is a joke (and a bad one at that) from Apple and co and they updated the Xcode library beofre the whole OS? This would be a wonderful step forward in computation. If I check which version of OS I have I get 10.14 howver all the Xcode folders have 10.15 in them. Criss-cross!

Comment: Yes, this just happened. The new version of MacOS is Catalina and has the number 10.15. The Xcode update arrived ahead of the OS update! Wonderful. :D Thanks for your replies but this seems to be an apple blunder again! I wonder what is next!

Comment: No I don't think it's the fault of Apple, it's whoever put that command line together.  They are specifying stuff which is very Xcode-version specific when there is no need to at all.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to MacOS Catalina (10.15) the problem disappeared. This means that Xcode got the update first which is crazy in my mind.